# How to extract table of information from an image (pdf.png....) and insert the infomation in a form then to a database using Angular/JEE and the OCR

Tags: java, node.js, angular, jakarta-ee, ocr

I want ro extract table from an image (pdf.png....) and insert the infomation in a form that holds the field where every information should be on.
Then inserting it to a database and save the information.
I want to use that with Angular/Java using OCR.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i don't have a specified code because m looking for a way to begin. i used Tesseract but it doesn't help with the process.

Comment: Stack overflow is a place where you have to show what you tried and so what you don't understand. Not a place where developper program for free. More than that there is not only one right way to do things and so we cannot just start a project for you

Comment: i don't want anyone to start a project for me like i said im looking for a way to do my task since people have experience here m just trying to take notes not asking someone for free projects